# Получить имя модуля в котором вызвана функция

Tags: c

Вопрос таков: есть-ли в си возможность получить имя модуля (заголовка), из которого вызвана функция (и в котором она описана)?

Например:

```
//simple.h
void foo();

//simple.c
void foo(){}

//main.c
#include "simple.h"
char name[] = getModuleName(foo());
printf("%s", name); // simple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без проблем.

Например, в макросе

```
#define DEBUG(l,e,t) \
  ((e) ? \
   0     \
   : debug_message(l, __STRING(e), t, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__))
```

в функцию `debug_message()` передаются

- аргумент 1;
- второй аргумент (обычно логическое выражение) в строковом виде;
- имя файла, в котором вызван `DEBUG`;
- номер строки в этм файле;
- имя фунции из которой вызван `DEBUG`